# Maintenance page logo is skewed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The other day [when Meta was down for a while](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/595690502382604290), we were all greeted with this `<sarcasm>`beautiful`</sarcasm>` page.

[image]

While it in itself could use some work, it is glaringly obvious that the Meta StackOverflow logo is skewed. Using the Web Developer Console, removing the width and height from the image fixed it. It's likely an oversight from when all the graphics were updated to SVG sprites a while back (the maintenance page image is still a PNG).

Comment: Why the sarcasm? That page is epic and has an implicit reference to a lot of discussion on the creation of meta here.

Comment: Also, for reference, the png (https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflowmeta/img/logo.png) raw dimensions are 230 x 42 . Noting that your screenshot shows 250x61 I would agree it is skewed.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm sure the presentation could be a little better than what they got going on there. I mean, I know it's a maintenance page so who really sees it, but c'mon! Give it some CSS-lovin'!

Comment: It could really just be a link to that image lol :) I like that they now have the twitter feed going so at least there is an avenue for getting feedback on what happened. Maybe I am too utilitarian, but I don't think css would make much of a difference here (aside from your noted issue with the logo).

Comment: *Skewed* might not mean what you think it does.  If it happened with your monitor image, would you use: (1) width and height adjustment, that's *stretched* (2) parallelogram adjustment, that's *skewed* (3) trapezoid or pincushion adjustments... I don't know any more specific term than *distorted*

Comment: @BenVoigt, now you have *skewered* this usage towards *distortion* ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed the logo dimensions for the offline maintenance pages for the trilogy sites (and their metas). This will take effect as of the next build, which is build 3762 for MSO, and build 2883 for the other sites.